# JQuery-UI Append() method leads to overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am **dragging** an element and dropping into a `container` ..using **drag and drop** *jquery-ui*.

when it drops , it **appends** an image to container using `append()` method.

```
$("#"+$(event.target).attr('id')+"").append(elementhtml);
```

Than I make that appended image draggable in a container

```
$("#id_of_image").draggable({axis:'y'});
```

Suppose *1st image* was appended at **place A** ,,. now suppose I have dragged  into **place B.**

Now if I `append` another image again on drag drop..Which will obviously `append` at **place B**...but *1st image*  is already there (by dragging) . which leads to **overlapping**. Is there any way I can append at empty spaces only.

I tried `insertAfter` method too but it acts same as append ,,

```
$(elementhtml).insertAfter($("#"+$(event.target).attr('id'))
.children("div:last-child"));
```

it does not check where the DOM element actually is.

I mean `append method` will append the image after checking where the empty space is and than append. Or after appending it slides to empty space and `avoid overlapping` or is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: same as this http://jsfiddle.net/T2HmG/1/  and problem is this - >http://puu.sh/lAsEr/d580d653f5.png

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still unable to understand the issue. Do you want to ensure that a dragged element should never be placed on top of another element?